# Special characters in tikz label

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

I have this code :

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    circle label/.style = {
        postaction={
            decoration={
                text along path,
                text = {#1},
                text align=center,
                reverse path,
            },
        decorate,
    }
    }
]
   \filldraw[white] (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
   \path[circle label={Text with spécial character}] (0,-1.2) arc (-90:360-90:1.2);
   \draw[dotted] (0,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have a problem to print the text that conatins special character (é). Is it possible to have labels with special characters? If yes how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use {} for special characters.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    circle label/.style = {
        postaction={
            decoration={
                text along path,
                text = {#1},
                text align=center,
                reverse path,
            },
        decorate,
    }
    }
]
   \filldraw[white] (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
   \path[circle label={Text with sp{é}cial character}] (0,-1.2) arc (-90:360-90:1.2);
   \draw[dotted] (0,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]